# Sha256 + salt algorithem in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, encryption, salt, sha, sha256

I want to encrypt my userid and password using SHA256 algorithm and salt key for sending to the server through a xml. How can I achieve this ?

I did a sample code with SHA256 and pasted bleow. How I use salt key in this ?

```
      void myBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
        var sha = new  SHA256Managed();
        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(testPass.Text);
        byte[] resultHash = sha.ComputeHash(bytes);
        string sha256 = ConvertToString(resultHash);
      }

       public static string ConvertToString(byte[] buff)
       {
         string sbinary = "";

         for (int i = 0; i < buff.Length; i++)
         {
             //hex-formatted
            sbinary += buff[i].ToString("X2");
         }
         return (sbinary);
       }
```

Comment: SHA256 isn't encryption. It's hashing. They're very different.

Comment: Note that this will only (slightly) protect you against people trying to find your plain text password. As the login procedure can be replayed, it won't protect you against hackers trying to reuse your authentication. You should use TLS/SSL to protect against replay attacks and use scrypt, bcrypt or PBKDF2 on the server to be better protected.

Answer (score 1):

SHA is a hash algorithm and not an encryption algorithm. The password cannot be extracted from your result string. Are you sure you are taking the right approach? Would you care to explain the scenario a bit better?

Comment: ah ok. but its ok. I dnt want to extract it from result. On server side they too compare it with the  result after using sha256 + salt.

Comment: @Stallin I understand better now. You might want to look at the Keyed Hash Algorithm which will encrypt your hash with a key. This is equivalent to salting. Here is a link: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.keyedhashalgorithm.aspx)